# Spring Framework Heavy Data Processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I am Using Spring Framework.

I want to process heavy Data, e.g for bill generation,Data Import, etc..
which is process by Database procedure and some via java code.
So please suggest me  in which way should i do this code.
visit http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-and-quartz-scheduler-example/

Should i use Spring-quartz, or Spring Batch...
Since Spring-quartz is use for Scheduling of job.
I don't want scheduling.. I want to Event to be Fire Directly.
And also, i am Using Database Store Procedure.. so what will be best..?

Comment: Why use spring at all?  Just use jdbc and some file i/o.

Comment: Sir, That operation is very heavy. I don't want this operation to be tight couple with application. i want light weight thread which will perform that opeartion, that why i ask this question

Comment: instead of concentrating on Spring Batch, which is just another abstraction layer on top of some basic functionality provided, for example, by Hibernate, concentrate on how Hibernate groups together updates and inserts to minimize memory consumption and number of sql statements sent to db, since this is what you really should be interested in. And, as far as I understand what you want, you should also use asynchronous processing, such as available in Spring. Take a look at:https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html  and https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/